# Dynamically call month in select statement in Python

Tags: python-3.x, variables, select

Edited with sample view of the dataframe:

```
Created_at,Count_of_sales
2018-03-01,123
2018-03-03,111
2018-03-06,10
2018-03-11,35
2018-03-18,22
2018-03-26,44
2018-03-30,30
2018-03-31,43
2018-04-02,21
2018-04-14,4
2018-04-22,36
```

I am writing a Python script that is scheduled to run on the beginning of each month. The script is expected to run to find the total sales for the previous month by store. I tried to define a variable that finds the max of previous month as shown below:

```
SELECT max(to_char(created_at,'yyyy-mm')) from fact_sales 
where to_char(created_at,'yyyy') in (select EXTRACT(year from 
CURRENT_DATE)) and to_char(created_at,'mm') in (select EXTRACT(month 
from CURRENT_DATE)-1)
```

I called the output of the above query as "ref_date" and then call this variable in the select statement as shown below:

```
select store,count(bill_id),to_char(bill_date,'yyyy-mm') 
from billing where to_char(bill_date,'yyyy-mm') = ref_date group by 
store,to_char(bill_date,'yyyy-mm')
```

Billing table view:

```
Store,Bill_ID,Bill_Date
A,123,2018-03-01
A,125,2018-03-06
A,126,2018-03-11
A,127,2018-03-18
A,128,2018-03-30
A,129,2018-03-31
A,131,2018-04-02
A,132,2018-04-14
A,135,2018-04-22
```

However when I run the above query I get the below error

ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 134))

Could anyone help. Thanks

Comment: Googling, I see that this strange error message has mystified others, and I don't really see why it appears. Try to make a small complete reproducible example, and I suppose some work-around can be found.

Comment: "Complete" means that I can just copy from here into a local file and run.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson, I have edited my initial post with a sample view of the Dataframe at hand. From this sample, I would like to filter our max date for previous month namely (03-31) and call that value in the below query:

select store,count(bill_id),to_char(bill_date,'yyyy-mm') 
from billing where to_char(dill_date,'yyyy-mm') = ref_date group by 
store,to_char(bill_date,'yyyy-mm')

Please let me know if this explains my requirement or would you need further info. Thanks..